# Как использовать аргументы в delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Добрый день? Я делаю программу для создания виджетов и **скринсейверов**. Мне надо узнать как создать программу которая видит аргументы и выводит их в Showmessage();. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26652

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screensaver в принципе обычное нативное приложение (win32 или 64), у которого поменяли расширение на ".scr". Просто в качестве параметров передается несколько значений. А дальше твоя программа вольна делать всё, что угодно - рисовать, не рисовать, показывать черный квадрат, реагировать на движение мышки или нажатие клавиш...